# flutter keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, keytool

Hi I am trying to release my flutter project so i went to create a key store I tried this command from flutter dev
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

but I've got this error

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of    
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+   keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks ...
+   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of    
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -val ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried running flutter doctor -v and copied the path after at java binary and tried this command

```
D:\Android studio\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

still the same so what is the issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this adding your path of Java jdk to your enviroment variables.

Once you've done that, you will use cmd to type de keytool. that's worked for me